# Not able to load Jupyter "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

My jupyter Notebook is not loading. I unsuccessfully tried loading it from Anaconda prompt as well.

```
(base) C:\Users\Ajit singh>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 29, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have already tried re installing Anaconda twice. Re installing didn't work

Comment: look at the last line of the error dump: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` and the line above it `import _ssl`. Possibly an ssl module is missing from the Python installation

Comment: yes understood. Not even able to import ssl module. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: There is likely some suitable [help available here at Stack Overflow for installing the Python ssl package on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+ssl+module+windows) for you.